# Unwanted Multiple Request in a Layout using NextJS App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm creating a NextJS (app router) application that will use a layout that includes a navigation. In the navigation I will need to load user information such as a username and a avatar. I've tried to use a layout file as the nextjs docs suggest to use but that wraps the page. I'm hoping to have the benefits of using a layout with data in (username) it using Suspense. I have a data file that should fetch data in this case mock data with a timeout for suspense to work. The data fetching is happening several times and my assumption was that this would only happen once. Why is this happening ?

```
export async function getUser() {
  const employee = {
    name: "John Doe",
  };
  console.log("Fetching user data...");
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  return employee.name;
}
```

I import that function into a component called UserInfo which is just a react component called the getUser function and returning the date.

```
import { getUser } from "@/app/lib/data";
export default async function UserInfo() {
   const data = await getUser();
  // console.log(data);
  return <>{`${data}`}</>;
}
```

Then in my layout file I have put suspense and my react component

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
    <UserInfo />
 </Suspense>
```

the fallback for Suspense is just a skeleton react component

The problem is when calling `getUser()` its being called multiple times which I thought would only run once. What am I doing wrong here ? Or is there another method of doing this that would be more performant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things.

If you use "use client" components, the code is running on the server and on the client, so the function would be called twice, but that should pose no problem.

If you have the user info only on the navigation, then make a navigation component and have the layout look something like this:

layout.tsx

```
<div className="flex flex-col">
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
    <Navigation />
  </Suspense>
  {children}
</div>
```

Navigation.tsx

```
export default async function page() {
  const data = await getUser()
  return (...)
}
```

Another pattern you could adopt is to fetch the user data once in your layout file and then provide it with React Context to all the child components, where you can use `useContext()` everywhere you need. That you need to do only though when you need the user data in the pages.

Comment: I'm trying your first example and I'm still seeing multiple console logs coming from the getUser function. Still scratching my head over here. Any other suggestions or additional information I can give to possibly solve this issue ?